# How to create timestamp in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having difficulties in creating a timestamp that will represent current time since epoch.
My timestamp accepts seconds and nanoseconds, example:

```
  created: {
    seconds: 1604584145
    nanos: 284689700
  }
```

This is my solution to get seconds:

```
  Int64 currentTimeInSec() {
    var ms = (new DateTime.now()).microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    return Int64((ms / 1000).round());
  }
```

However, I'm having difficulties in finding a way to get nanos.

Regards :)

Comment: `DateTime` has max microsecond precision, and, no: 1 sec != 1000 [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)

Comment: Using `ms` for "microseconds" instead of "milliseconds" is very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, [Dart provides only microsecond precision](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24306).  I'd generate your timestamp with:

```dart
import 'package:fixnum/fixnum.dart';

class Timestamp {
  Timestamp.current() {
    final totalMicroseconds = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    seconds = totalMicroseconds ~/ (1000 * 1000);

    final microseconds = totalMicroseconds % (1000 * 1000);
    nanoseconds = microseconds * 1000;
  }

  Int64 seconds;
  Int64 nanoseconds;
}
```